# Scale video view based on the aspect ratio

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc

I want to scale a video stream on devices with different screen sizes. The sender's video size can be different also.

The code what I have till now:

```
public func videoView(_ videoView: RTCEAGLVideoView, didChangeVideoSize size: CGSize) {
        // scale by height
        let w = renderer.bounds.height * size.width / size.height
        let h = renderer.bounds.height
        let x = (w - renderer.bounds.width) / 2
        renderer.frame = CGRect(x: -x, y: 0, width: w, height: h)
    }
```

The renderer is a view where the video is rendered in. This scales, but not in the right way. Some part of the video is lost, the height is fine. But the width is cropped what I understand.

Is it possible to achieve a solution that displays the video full screen (on the receiver side) without losing its aspect ratio?

Comment: after 3 years 6months you made my day... due to some reason I have to use 2017 version of WebRTC. Thank you very much. Your question was my answer. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `AVMakeRect(aspectRatio:insideRect)`. This method finds the minimum rect that preserves the aspectRatio inside the specified rect.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/1390116-avmakerect)

In general you will specify your `UIScreen` bounds as an `insideRect:` parameter and the size of your media in `aspectRatio`. There might be a case where the rect would be slightly smaller than your `UIScreen` size. In that case i suggest using technique called [letter boxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letterboxing_(filming))